# Vintage mode: moving farthest left or right within a wrapped line

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am in the process of switching to Vintage mode, and I would like to turn off my arrow keys. However, what's stopping me is not knowing how to move farthest left or right within a wrapped line. For example, within a markdown file paragraph.

I achieve this with command + arrow left or arrow right, depending on where I need the cursor. What's the equivalent of this in vintage mode?

Just to be explicitly clear, I am not trying to get to the beginning or end of the entire line, I am trying to move the cursor to the beginning or end of the wrapped it is currently sitting in.

**Edit**

Adding an image to illustrate what I am trying to do. The arrows indicate where I would want the cursor to jump to with the proper left or right keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to you Key Binding - User
2. Add following key bindings

   ```
   ,{ "keys": ["super+0"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
   ,{ "keys": ["super+1"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} }
   ```
3. Save and you can use command+0 / command+1 to go to end/start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

While in command mode, `0` for beginning of line and `$` for end of line.

Comment: No, as I stated I am not looking to get to the beginning or end of the *line*. I want to get to the start or end of the wrapped line the cursor is sitting in.

Comment: My mistake, I thought I had that a single long line when I tested it but I guess not. Anyways, if you want something more vim like, you could rebind the command and args Tony specified and bind it to 0 and $ in command mode.